# How to send notification to android and ios device using firebase?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications

I am trying to send the foreground and background notification to selected `Android` and `ios` device through the `Java` code. I was using the following `Json` for both platform

```
{
"data": {
    "appointmentId": 156913762771107,
    "click_action": "com.invite",
    "body": "Yay! Message"
},
"to": "eY0euHbZ0-s:APA91bFYUT-jxfuOLiqfJ5BsjGU9a2KHXE39g_gUkO4_hpmPIPeIqTauhNBYj50Jniyzx0_9aRTHoezugYPcshA9dDs60YoEWAno3gJEUYxfMzgtcjy4mVC5RuSqT_RRJN6RVkgWVyMf",
"notification": {
    "click_action": "com.invite",
    "body": "Yay! Message",
    "sound": "default",
    "badge": 1,
    "content_available": true
 }
}
```

Everything was working fine a few months back but now it stopped working. I tried to search for the common `Json` which can be used for both platforms but couldn't find the solution.

Comment: which version of library do you use? do you check device tokens? Doesn pushes came to the device?

Comment: Yes, everything is correct on the configuration side. I can see the notification If I send through firebase console.

Comment: Probably the JSON structure for cloud messaging is changed with firebase update

Comment: Yes, but I couldn't find the correct JSON